# how to disable password Complexity requirement on window server

Tags: window

can any body tell me how to disable Password Complexity Requirement on window server 2003
i try but the disable option on security policy is disable(the radio button)

Answer (score 1):

If It's disabled probably it's comming from a domain GPO:

```
http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-pt/library/cc875814.aspx
```

If you really need to disable it, you have two options:

Disable de policy (will affect the all domain or OU).

Move your server to a diferent OU, if the policy is just linked to a particular OU.